# Como selecionar um blob do banco de dados e transformar em bitmap?

Tags: android, imagem, sqlite, android-camera

Estou com o seguinte erro no meu projeto, eu seleciono uma imagem da galeria transformo ela em byte cadastro no banco, porem no momento de carregar ela pra imageView ela não aparece e não da erro na aplicação, eu não estou mexendo na parte do código de tirar foto mas se alguém tiver algum código melhor pois esse a imagem perde a qualidade, agradeço a ajuda.

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0, SELECT_FILE = 1;
    private Button btnSelect;
    private Button btnCamera;
    private Button btnSave;
    private ImageView ivImage;
    private String Chave;
    banco db = new banco(this);
    SQLiteDatabase banco;
    String local;
    byte[] imagem;

    Bitmap bitmap;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        btnSelect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelect);
        btnCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSalvar);


        btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Chave = "Selecionar";
                galleryIntent();

            }
        });

        btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Chave = "Camera";
                cameraIntent();

            }
        });

        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                banco = db.getReadableDatabase();
                banco.execSQL("insert into tabela (imagem) values('"+imagem+"')");
                Toast.makeText(Main.this, imagem+" Imagem salva!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                banco.close();

            }
        });

        carregar();

    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case Utility.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if(Chave.equals("Camera"))
                        cameraIntent();
                    else if(Chave.equals("Selecionar"))
                        galleryIntent();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void galleryIntent()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),SELECT_FILE);
    }

    private void cameraIntent()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
            else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
                onCaptureImageResult(data);
        }

    }

    private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
        bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

        File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

        local = destination.getName();

        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
            destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ivImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

        bitmap = null;
        if (data != null) {
            try {

                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        ivImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable)ivImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream saida = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap2.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,saida);
        imagem = saida.toByteArray();

        Toast.makeText(Main.this, imagem.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }




    public void carregar() {

        banco = db.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cur = banco.rawQuery("select * from tabela", null);

        cur.moveToFirst();

        if(cur.isAfterLast()== false) {

            cur.moveToLast();

            byte[] image = cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex("imagem"));

            if (image != null) {
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
                ivImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Você confirmou se aquele `byte[] image` no método `carregar()` não é nulo?

Answer (score 1):

Sua imagem certamente é muito grande para ser desenha na `surface` de um bitmap, pois estoura o tamanho máximo permitido para a memória de textura do Android. Se você usar o *Android Monitor* dentro do *Android Studio* verá um monte de aviso do tipo *“Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture”*. Você precisa fazer *downsampling* da mesma. Evite manipular bitmaps diretamente, use uma biblioteca para isso. É muito mais complicado lidar com bitmaps no android do que se imagina. Muito mesmo!

**Nota:** *Em casos de pouca memória de sistema restante, as operações leitura do arquivo para um array de bytes em memória pode falhar. Em situações extremas de pouca memória, nem mesmo usar uma biblioteca com o Glide pode evitar que esses erros ocorram, mas o Glide lida graciosamente com os mesmos, mais uma vantagem de usar uma biblioteca como essa.*

Por isso estude a biblioteca [Glide do Google](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), que faz todo o trabalho para você de ler a imagem em uma thread em background (evitando travar a interface do usuário) e ainda considera rotações de orientação da tela (que lhe dariam uma exceção de `NullReferenceException`), e ainda implementa um cache de imagens para melhorar a performance da aplicação.

Instale o Glide adicionando a seguinte linha no seu Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

Uma vez instalado o glide modifique sua rotina de exibição para:

```
public void carregar() {

    banco = db.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cur = banco.rawQuery("select * from tabela", null);

    cur.moveToFirst();

    if(cur.isAfterLast()== false) {

        cur.moveToLast();

        byte[] image = cur.getBlob(cur.getColumnIndex("imagem"));

        if (image != null) {

            Glide.with(this)
                .load(image)
                .asBitmap()
                .into(ivImage);

        }
    }
```

**Nota:** *Percebi um erro na sua implementação da captura da imagem pela câmera. Você está pegando apenas a miniatura da imagem capturada. Esse é um erro/pegadinha comum de quem começa a trabalhar com a câmera no Android. Tenho uma resposta exatamente sobre isso que você pode ver aqui:* [Trabalhando com a câmera ou galeria](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/160346/57894)

Comment: Se fosse esse o problema(imagem muito grande) não daria erro?

Comment: @ramaral Não. O erro fica escondido porque o Android prefere evitar derrubar uma aplicação por causa de uma imagem muito grande e apenas emite um aviso (warning) e não exibe nada. Se você olhar no *Android Studio* na aba *Android Monitor* verá um monte de mensagem do tipo *“Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture”* .

Comment: Em todas as situações idênticas com que me deparei foi disparado o *OutOfMemoryError*. O problema deve estar noutro lado(aquele método `carregar()` é um pouco "estranho"), ainda mais por ele poder estar a usar a miniatura e não a imagem.

Comment: @ramaral certamente não foram situações idênticas. Estou te afirmando que o erro é o que relatei, não tenho a menor dúvida. O método carregar não é estranho. Apenas pega um blob do banco. O uso da miniatura é um erro conceitual, mas, inclusive, com a miniatura tudo vai parecer funcionar, pois a imagem é pequena e vai caber na *memória de textura* do android. E isso é o ponto importante: o bitmap da galeria é grande demais para caber nessa memória, não na memória do android em geral. Pode ocorrer `OutOfMemoryError` se tiver com memória do sistema baixa. Vou deixar mais claro na resposta.

Comment: Não vou teimar mas estamos a falar de uma miniatura e não da imagem. Nunca tal me aconteceu sem dar erro. Quando falo estranho é por isto: `cur.moveToFirst();if(cur.isAfterLast()== false){cur.moveToLast(); ...}` não quer dizer que não faça o que ele quer é apenas uma forma estranha de ir para o último registo(se é o que ele quer).

Comment: Já tive experiência de ao salvar a imagem direto no Sqlite, tive alguns problemas com `OutOfMemoryError`, pois os limites de tamanho em alguns tipos de variáveis é bem baixo,(além de que o Sqlite tem algumas limitações quanto ao tamanho da query e do registro), acabei optando em sempre criar um arquivo, passar esse arquivo para a câmera e gravar o `path` desse arquivo no banco. Esse tema é discutido [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

Comment: @ramaral não quis parar para ensinar a ele como usar os cursores ou banco de dados, porque ele teria que colocar uma ordem ali. Se você quiser comprovar o que eu disse sobre o problema não ser outOfMemoryError, é só criar um simples programa para exibir as imagens da galeria. Ele não usa só a miniatura! Isso só quando vai pela câmera. O problema dele maior é quando seleciona pela galeria. O android hoje tem mais de 1, 2 e 4 GB de memória... qualquer bitmap cabe na memória. Certamente não é esse o caso (exceto em situações de pouca memória do sistema)

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro eu mesmo indiquei para o mesmo usuário que fez essa pergunta que essa não é a melhor forma de guardar imagens. Minha resposta pode ser vista aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/159944/trabalhando-com-imagens-de-alta-qualidade-no-sqlite3/160040#160040

Comment: @Loudenvier `OutOfMemoryError` pode ser disparado por não ter `heap memory` suficiente para aquela variável. Não importa se o dispositivo tem muitos GB de memória, as variáveis tem seu tamanho limitado.

Comment: @LucasQueirozRibeiro eu sei que essa pode ser uma causa, mas não é o que está acontecendo nesse caso relatado pelo usuário. Isso acontece para TODAS as imagens da galeria que ela exibe. Se ele escolher uma do whatsapp vai funcionar porque ela é menor. Se está em dúvida é só escrever um app em 5min que exiba uma imagem selecionada pela galeria em um image view. Não vai dar OutOfMemory e vai dar o aviso que informei... Claro, se o seu celular não estiver com baixa memória livre. Atualizei a resposta para ser mais claro nesse assunto.

Comment: Ótima leitura sobre o assunto: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10271095/285678

Answer (score 0):

Segue um exemplo básico de como manipular as imagens no Sqlite:

ADICIONAR IMAGEM:

```
public void add( byte[] image) throws SQLiteException{
    ContentValues cv = new  ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_IMAGE,   image);
    database.insert( DB_TABLE, null, cv );
}
```

Para carregar a imagem use o método `getBlob` :

```
byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(1);
```