# Trabalhando com imagens de alta qualidade no sqlite3

Tags: java, android, imagem, sqlite3

Na minha aplicação eu faco a seleção de uma imagem da galeria, em seguida eu salvo ela no banco, porem se a imagem tem uma qualidade alta o app não salva, além de não salvar ele para de funcionar, tem alguma forma de salvar essa imagem no banco mesmo sendo com uma qualidade boa ou não deixar o usuário salvar aquela imagem e mandar uma mensagem pra ele ?

```
public class Horarios extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0, SELECT_FILE = 1;
    private Button btnSelect;
    private Button btnCamera;
    private String Chave;
    BancoDeDados db = new BancoDeDados(this);
    SQLiteDatabase banco;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.horarios);


        btnSelect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelect);
        btnCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCamera);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fabH);

        btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Chave = "Selecionar";
                galleryIntent();


            }
        });

        btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Chave = "Camera";
                cameraIntent();

            }
        });

        fab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                insertImg(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(Horarios.this, "Imagem Salva!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                finish();
            }
        });


        //carregar imagem

        byte[] imageFinal = getImage();

        if(imageFinal != null){

            try {

                imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageFinal,0,imageFinal.length));

                imageView.invalidate();

            } catch(Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(Horarios.this, "erro:" +e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }


    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case Utility.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if(Chave.equals("Camera"))
                        cameraIntent();
                    else if(Chave.equals("Selecionar"))
                        galleryIntent();
                }
                break;
        }

        Toast.makeText(Horarios.this, "testetando o codigo 111111", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
            else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
                onCaptureImageResult(data);
        }

    }




    private void galleryIntent()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),SELECT_FILE);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

        bitmap = null;
        if (data != null) {
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }




    private void cameraIntent()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    }

    private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
        bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);

        File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
        FileOutputStream fo;

        try {
            destination.createNewFile();
            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }



    public void insertImg(Bitmap img ) {

        byte[] data = getBitmapAsByteArray(img);

        banco = db.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
        content.put("imagem", data);

        banco.insert("Horarios", null, content);

    }
    public static byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);
        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }



    public byte[] getImage(){
        byte[] result = null;

        banco = db.getReadableDatabase();

        String qu = "select imagem from Horarios";
        Cursor cur = banco.rawQuery(qu, null);

        if (cur.moveToLast()){
            result = cur.getBlob(0);
            cur.close();
        }
        if (cur != null && !cur.isClosed()) {
            cur.close();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Amigo, sem você publicar o seu código será impossível responder essa pergunta de forma correta. Eu imagino que o problema seja consumo de memória ao carregar o bitmap completo sem realizar uma downsampling do mesmo (algo automaticamente realizado se você usar uma biblioteca de imagem, como Glide). Publique seu código, ou essa pergunta pode até acabar sendo fechada pelos moderadores! Pelo menos a parte que lê a imagem e a grava. Outra coisa: não guarde imagem no banco de dados, mas sim em arquivo e apenas guarde o caminho dela no banco.

Comment: então se vc tiver o código ou algum link que me ajude a salvar apenas o caminho e puder me enviar eu agradeço

Comment: a parte da câmera esta deixando a foto que é tirada ilegível, mais se eu conseguir arrumar a parte que seleciona talvez eu ate tire o recurso da câmera

Comment: Tenho a solução para ambos os problemas. Mas preciso separar o código e formatar pra postar na resposta. Acho que consigo até amanhã, pois ainda estou trabalhando.

Comment: Observei que você insere em *Horarios* os bytes da imagem e na abertura da *activity* você dá um select em horários e pega o primeiro que vier, retornando o  byte array da imagem que gravou lá... Isso não garantirá que você pegará a última imagem nunca. Isso me parece um problema no código, mas vou responder apenas sobre a parte de gravação da imagem.

Comment: nossa muito obrigado, salvou minha vida, vou aguardar então, desculpa o abuso mas se puder me ajudar com mais um problema, na minha aplicação tenho uma especie de sistema de eventos , aonde eu salvo a data do evento , gostaria de fazer uma notificação , pesquisando achei alguns códigos porem eles só executam a notificação na hora, minha intenção é que apareça mesmo com o aplicativo em segundo plano, se vc não tiver o código mas tiver pelo menos um link q me ajude já sou grato

Comment: realmente não avia percebido o moveToLast esta dentro do if era pra estar fora, mas não estou tendo problemas esta funcionando corretamente, se perceber mais alguma observação peço que me avise, sou novo no desenvolvimento android, estou desenvolvendo meu TCC e tudo que aprendi ate agora foi na internet, ainda não tive a oportunidade de pagar um curso mais pretendo pq gostei muito

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47100/discussion-between-loudenvier-and-vitor-hugo).

Comment: Sobre os demais problemas, por exemplo, o de pegar as imagens da câmera, você pode abrir uma nova questão! Com um título específico. Sobre as notifcações em segundo plano, mesma coisa: abra uma outra pergunta e tente especificar bem o que não consegue fazer (senão ela pode ser considerada muito ampla!). Se faltou algo na resposta, ou ficou alguma dúvida, comente lá que atualizo a mesma na medida do meu tempo :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiramente, como somos bons desenvolvedores, [somos também preguiçosos](http://blogoscoped.com/archive/2005-08-24-n14.html?_ga=1.238592387.2085177421.1476924974): não vamos inventar a roda! Lidar com imagens no Android não é simples, portanto usaremos uma biblioteca para facilitar nossa vida. Os benefícios serão muitos. E como não podemos confiar em tudo quanto é projeto *open source* por aí, usaremos logo um do próprio Google e incluiremos no seu projeto uma referência para o [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) (uma breve [introdução à mesma](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en)).

Para adicionar o Glide no seu projeto inclua sua dependência no arquivo Gradle do projeto:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

O Glide é uma biblioteca que remove praticamente toda a complexidade em carregar imagens (e redimensioná-las também) no android, inclusive com efeitos de *fade* e tudo mais. Mas ela também pode ser usada para processar o bitmap, o redimensionando, etc.

*Não é boa prática, exceto se for necessidade de negócio, incluir as imagens em si, como um blob, no banco de dados. O banco fica enorme, as operações de recuperação são lentas, não dá para usar uma biblioteca de leitura de imagens direto (tem que carregar o array de bytes pra memória primeiro), etc. Portanto iremos copiar a imagem selecionada e grava-la-emos em outro diretório, armazenando apenas essa url no banco e nada mais (veremos isso mais abaixo)*

Vamos renomear `getImage` para `getImagePath` e retornaremos o campo imageUrl ao invés do campo imagem. Também adicionamos uma cláusula `order by desc` que retorna os horários mais recentes primeiro e também uma cláusula `limit 1` que retornará apenas o primeiro registro encontrado, logo, o mais recente, pois está em ordem. Assim não fazemos o potencialmente muito lento `moveToLast()`:

```
public byte[] getImagePath(){
    banco = db.getReadableDatabase();

    // mude o campoData por um campo com data e hora da inserção, ou
    // pelo id autoincremento (que é sequencial) para forçar a ordem cronológica     
    String qu = "select imagemUrl from Horarios order by campoData desc limit 1";
    Cursor cur = banco.rawQuery(qu, null);

    if (cur.moveToFirst()){
        result = cur.getString(0);
        cur.close();
    }
    if (cur != null && !cur.isClosed()) {
        cur.close();
    }
    // faltava fechar o banco
    banco.close();

    return result;
}
```

Agora modificamos a parte de leitura da imagem no *onCreate* para:

```
//carregar imagem
String path = getImagePath();
if(path != null) {
    Glide
        .with(this) // se for fragment use getActivity()
        .load(path)
        .centerCrop() // manterá as proporções se não forem equivalentes à image view
        .into(imageView);
}
```

Vamos atualizar nossa rotina de selecionar a imagem da galeria. Ela precisa copiar a `Uri` retornada pelo Android, que aponta para uma imagem sob a qual não temos controle! Essa imagem pode estar na Galeria do Android (e ser apaga a qualquer momento), pode ser uma imagem do WhatsApp (que apagamos toda hora). Portanto, chamaremos o `copyImageToAppFolder()` que irá copiar a imagem para um local que esteja sob a tutela do nosso aplicado. Vou usar uma rotina bem interessante de cópia que criei para atender praticamente todos os cenários que pude antever (o mesmo que uso em código profissional de apps já publicados no Google Play). Essa rotina sabe decodificar as Uri´s retornadas pelo Android pelo seletor de documentos:

```
private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
    if (data == null)
        return;
    Uri uri = data.getData();
    String imageUrl = copyImageToAppFolder(uri);
    if (imageUrl != null) {
        Glide
            .with(this)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .centerCrop() 
            .into(imageView);    
        insertImg(imageUrl);
    }
    fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private String copyImageToAppFolder(uri) {
    String dir = getAppDir(); // implemente essa rotina
    String filename = "imagem_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
    String destination = new File(dir, filename).getPath();
    Files.copy(this, uri, destination);
    return destination;
}
```

Note que o `insertImg` não é mais o antigo, que recebia um Bitmap. Ele agora recebe um String com o caminho da imagem.

```
public void insertImg(String path) {

    banco = db.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
    content.put("imagemUrl", path);

    banco.insert("Horarios", null, content);
}
```

A classe utilitária para realizar cópias de arquivos em android é um pouco grande, mas bastante versátil:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;

import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;

public final class Files {

    // Copy file from a Uri retrieved from ACTION_GET_CONTENT, using a ContentResolver
    public static boolean copy(Context context, Uri fromUri, String to) {
        try {
            FileInputStream inStream = (FileInputStream)context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(fromUri);
            return copy(inStream, to);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static boolean copy(FileDescriptor from, String to) {
        FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(from);
        return copy(inStream, to);
    }
    public static boolean copy(FileInputStream from, String to) {
        FileOutputStream outputStream;
        try {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(to);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            try { if (from != null) from.close(); }
            catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            return false;
        }
        return copy(from, outputStream);
    }
    public static boolean copy(FileInputStream inStream, FileOutputStream outStream) {
        FileChannel inChannel = null;
        FileChannel outChannel = null;
        try{
            try {
                inChannel = inStream.getChannel();
                outChannel = outStream.getChannel();
                long bytesTransferred = 0;
                while(bytesTransferred < inChannel.size()){
                    bytesTransferred += inChannel.transferTo(
                            bytesTransferred, inChannel.size() - bytesTransferred, outChannel);
                }
                return true;
            }
            finally {
                if (inChannel != null) inChannel.close();
                if (outChannel != null) outChannel.close();
                if (inStream != null) inStream.close();
                if (outStream != null) outStream.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Com essas modificações acredito que seu programa funcione corretamente.

Comment: estou implementando o código, na parte de selecionar a imagem apareceu o seguinte erro, String imageUrl = data.getData(); o metodo getData retorna um Uri não uma string, tem o método getDataString eu mudo o método ?

Comment: Vou mudar o código, como escrevi aqui e não no AndroidStudio acabei não vendo. O método `Files.copy` também aceita uma `Uri` no primeiro parâmetro! Para converter uma `Uri` para string, chame o `toString()` do objeto `Uri`

Comment: estou testando por partes, e a parte de selecionar a imagem vc seleciona e a imagem não aparece no imageView

Comment: @VitorHugo estranho... somente se o imageUrl for nulo é que isso poderia acontecer. Você tem como depurar pra ver? Ou colocar um alerta se for nulo? Tem como verificar se o imageView não está invisível tb? Se a imageUrl estiver correta, não tem erro, vai aparecer sim! Outra coisa: vi agora que você apenas insere a imagem no banco quando clica no FAB, da forma que fiz estou inserindo sempre que seleciona uma imagem!

Comment: eu comentei a linha de insert so para fazer o teste, coloquei um toast e informei o Uri (imageUrl.toString()) e esta aparecendo um caminho (content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/2)

Comment: Entendi o que está acontecendo. É a nova forma como o android retorna itens selecionados. Vamos exibir então a imagem já copiada. Mudarei o código agora.

Comment: a um detalhe nao sei se é isso quando colei o codigo deu erro no path entao deu alt+enter e ele importou (import static android.R.attr.path;)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47105/discussion-between-loudenvier-and-vitor-hugo).

Comment: consegui implementar quase tudo falta apenas o Files, que sinceramente não to entendendo, vc não teria um link mostrando como implementar o mesmo ?

Comment: @VitorHugo o files é uma classe que eu mesmo escrevi do zero. Cria um arquivo Java pra essa classe e cola o. Código todo lá... Aí é só reusar

Comment: eu fiz um teste para ver se ia dar erro, eu apaguei na galeria a imagem que estava sendo usada no app, e nao apareceu erro algum e a imagem continuou la

Comment: Loudenvier se puder me ajudar em outra questão  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/160332/trabalhando-com-c%C3%A2mera-e-galeria