# Trabalhando com câmera e galeria

Tags: android, android-camera, galeria

Estou com o seguinte problema, na minha aplicação eu tiro uma foto e apresento ela em uma `imageView`, porem quando eu tiro a foto ela fica com a qualidade boa na galeria só que na `imageView` não, se for um texto não da nem mesmo para ler, abaixa eu vou colocar o código da câmera

```
private void cameraIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
}

private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);

    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
    FileOutputStream fo;

    try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Eu imagino que mudando a maneira como busca a foto resolva o problema.

Nessa mesma aplicação também tem a opção de selecionar uma imagem da galeria e nessa opção a imagem vem perfeita sem alteração na qualidade.

```
 private void galleryIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),SELECT_FILE);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
    if (data == null)
        return;
    imagemUrl = data.getDataString();
    if (imagemUrl != null) {
        Glide
                .with(this)
                .load(imagemUrl)
                .into(imageView);
    }
    fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema é simples, mas é também fonte de confusão comum de quem está começando a trabalhar com captura de imagens com `Intent` no android.

O **'X'** da questão está aqui: `bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");`

Esse campo do Extras, retornado pela intenção de câmera, não guarda a imagem capturada, mas sim um pequeno *thumbnail* (miniatura) da imagem.

O correto, ao se trabalhar com a câmera no android, é informar à intenção de câmera o arquivo destino que você deseja que seja gerado com a imagem capturada (em resolução total). Para isso use o código abaixo:

```
Uri outputUri;

private void cameraIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // outputUri precisa apontar para um arquivo que seu app tenha direito de gravar
    outputUri = getTempCameraUri();
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
}

private Uri getTempCameraUri() {
    try {
        // uso createTempFile por conveniência
        File file = File.createTempFile("camera", ".jpg", this.getExternalCacheDir());
        // se estiver em um Fragment, use getActivity() ao invés de this na linha anterior
        return Uri.fromFile(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Após a execução da intenção da câmera, quando o usuário retornar, a foto tirada pelo usuário estará gravada em `outputUri`. Agora basta modificar seu código para:

```
private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    if (outputUri == null)
        return;

    Glide
        .with(this)
        .load(outputUri)
        .centerCrop() // não deixe de aplicar alguma transformação!!!
        .into(imageView);
    }
    fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

E voilà!

Comment: não deu certo, pelo teste que eu fiz ele não esta gravando nada dentro da variável outputUri, por esse motivo não esta carregando nada na imageview, porem a imagem esta sendo gravada na galeria

Comment: @VitorHugo Você tem que atribuir um valor para outputUri conforme eu disse, senão ela vai ser passada como `null` para a câmera. Não é a câmera que decide onde gravar e preenche outputUri com um valor, ela USA o valor que você passou em outputUri para gravar naquele local que VOCÊ informou. Eu normalmente gero um arquivo temporário antes. Você preencheu outputUri e a câmera não gravou nada ali? Foi isso? Ou não preencheu com um valor?

Comment: eu imaginei que essa linha (    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputUri);
) gravava um valor dentro da outputUri, como faço para pegar a Uri da imagem que foi gerada ?

Comment: @VitorHugo essa linha apenas coloca o conteúdo do outputUri no extra do intent que vai pra câmera. Logo o outputUri já tem que estar com um caminho definido por você pra onde será gravada a imagem. É uma forma de passar um parâmetro pro intent indicando o caminho da imagem que vc quer que seja gravado. Amanhã de manhã vou editar a resposta pra deixar isso mais claro.

Comment: a unica maneira que sei de pegar o valor Uri e através do Intent data que não esta dando certo, vou aguardar, obrigado novamente, você é o único que esta me ajudando, imaginei que teria mais programadores android

Comment: @VitorHugo é bm simples resolver isso! Você só precisa construir a Uri dado um caminho. Vou atualizar o código com uma rotina que cria um arquivo temporário o qual você pode depois passar para o insertDb a URI que vai ser copiada, com as selecionadas pela galeria... No futuro você pode até já fazer a cãmera gravar direto nesse diretório, ou se preferir jogar no diretório local depois, lebre-se de apagar o temporário que criar, para não deixar um monte de fotos no temporário e no diretório apontado pelo BD.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47210/discussion-between-vitor-hugo-and-loudenvier).